# MySQL join another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 2 tables as follow ::

order table ::

```
order_id    |    store_id    |  member_id    |     create_tstamp   
  90                2              15             28/07/2014  15:35:00
  91                2              16             29/07/2014  16:11:12
  92                2              15             30/07/2014  08:07:12
  93                2              15             01/08/2014  09:33:12
```

transferPayment table ::

```
transfer_id    | order_id  |  amount  |   transfer_time      |  create_tstamp
   1               90         1000      30/07/2014 11:00:00   30/07/2014 12:00:00
   2               90         800       30/07/2014 11:00:00   30/07/2014 13:14:56
   3               90         956       30/07/2014 11:00:00   30/07/2014 14:16:17
   4               91         385       01/08/2014 14:35:00   01/08/2014 16:18:17
   5               91         390       01/08/2014 14:35:00   01/08/2014 16:30:17
   6               92         198       05/08/2014 15:11:11   06/08/2014 17:18:18
```

I want to join two tables.The condition is  order table much be join transferPayment table that have order_id same as and create_tstamp in transferPayment table is recently only.

Finally. There will be result as follows:

```
order_id    |    store_id    |  member_id    |     create_tstamp   | transfer_id  | amount |  transfer_time     | create_tstamp
  90               2             15            28/07/2014 15:35:00        3          956   30/07/2014 11:00:00   30/07/2014 13:14:56   
  91               2             16            29/07/2014  16:11:12       5          390   01/08/2014 14:35:00   01/08/2014 16:30:17
  92               2             15            30/07/2014  08:07:12       6          198   05/08/2014 15:11:11   06/08/2014 17:18:18
```

**What is MySQL command** to slove this?

Comment: The fist Mysql command is the highest of them all:learn about JOINs!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to get most recent transferPayment you'll have to use `max(transfer_id)` and `group by order_id`
like below query maybe?

```
SELECT o.order_id,o.store_id,o.member_id,o.create_tstamp as order_create_tstamp,
       t.transfer_id,t.amount,t.transfer_time,t.create_tstamp as transfer_create_tstamp
FROM
  transferPayment t
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT max(transfer_id) as transfer_id,order_id
   FROM transferPayment
   GROUP BY order_id) t2
ON t.transfer_id = t2.transfer_id AND t.order_id = t2.order_id
INNER JOIN
  `order` o
ON o.order_id = t.order_id
```

here's the [sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/80e0c/4/0)

Answer (score 1):

As far as the join query goes, this should work:

```
SELECT *
FROM order_table
INNER JOIN transfer_payment
ON order_table.order_id=transfer_payment.order_id;
```

However to me it's unclear what your exact conditions are (order by date, etc?), could you try making that a bit clearer?

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM (order JOIN transferPayment ON order.order_id = transferPayment.order_id)
WHERE order.create_tstamp = transferPayment.create_tstamp;
```

I did not quite understand if you want to order it by something but this will join the same 'order_id' and show the rows with same 'create_tstamp'